# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Number -> Number -> Number]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Number

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm not sure what is going on here.  The application was working fine then I came in to work on it and kept getting this error.  My Compiler doesn't show errors, and I do not have any nulls in the code (or at least I don't think i do.)  Here is what the console looks like:

[image: Chrome console output]

Any help would be appreciated here.  I'm trying to learn TS, Angular, and RxJS so still a noob.  lol

Comment: Whats injected in the `constructor` of `BugDetailsComponent`

Comment: `constructor(public Bug_Number: number,
                public Bug_Name: string,
                public Created_By: string,
                public Detail: string,
                public Date_Started: number,
                public Date_Completed: number,
                public Date_Days_Worked: number,
                public Completed: string) {
    }`

Answer (score 4):

We inject dependencies using the `constructor` generally.

Read this: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Your code should be

```
//...
public Bug_Number: number, 
public Bug_Name: string, 
public Created_By: string, 
public Detail: string, 
public Date_Started: number, 
public Date_Completed: number, 
public Date_Days_Worked: number, 
public Completed: string
constructor() { }
//...
```

We usually inject a service/class by marking them as injectable using the [`@Injectable`](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable) decorator

Example: Bug Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BugService {
  constructor() { }
  // getBug()
  // getBugById(bugId: number)
  // addBug(Bug bug)
}
```

And inject it in component like,

```
constructor(bugService: BugService) { }
```

and access them anywhere in page like `this.bugService.getBugs()`

Comment: I think I may have not explained the problem correctly.  I am trying to pass the above variables from a button press method to this class so i can manipulate them.  If I do it as this is suggested, how would i import them into the class?  Now that I'm thinking about it, it may be beneficial to see the code.  Here is the GitHub:

https://github.com/Zapakna/NewBugZapper.git